# How to cleanly delete my own answer put under the wrong question?

Tags: discussion, moderation, answer-quality

For my education, I browse old question and see their answers.

I found [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41521/can-anyone-tell-if-a-wireless-router-is-plugged-into-an-ethernet-port-without-a) dealing with how to detect wifi access point on a large network *and with no accepted answer*. This reminded of my reading of a very interesting chapter in Fyodor's Nmap book dealing exactly with this issue and describing an advanced used of nmap to this goal relying on several criterions to reduce the false positives.

I found that both the reference to this book and a summary description of this technique would be helpful,.

However by mistake I added this answer to a [wrong question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32017/how-to-track-down-a-rogue-laptop-connected-to-an-un-protected-ethernet-socket-in) linked to this one but I deleted this wrong answer immediately to post it under the right question.

But my new answer was also deleted by the moderation team accusing me of spamming.

I honestly thought that deleting my wrong post was the way to do and did not intend any spamming. How should I proceed next time I put my answer under the wrong tab (during my researches I may have many SE tabs in my browser)?

And as a side note I'm not sure to understand why the moderators are so sure that my answer is so useless that it needs to be trashed away, but if you think so you are the boss here :( ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time if the situation happens again, I will try to proceed as follow:

1. Replace the wrong answer by some text telling it is a mistake to be deleted,
2. "Delete" it,
3. Then paste the answer under the right question.

This should avoid useless notifications, provide a better view  over what is going on, and avoid any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5):

the 'duplicate answers' flag is automated, so the mods get notified any time this happens.

I reacted to the flag first - at the time you hadn't deleted the wrong one, so I quickly looked them over, left you the comment and deleted them both, expecting you to review and post as needed - deciding which one you wanted to answer if any?

Hadn't seen that you had also deleted a post, so my apologies there. I can undelete one for you just now.

Comment: My apologize too for the wrong post, I will have to be more careful next time :). It seems you already have undeleted the right post, so thank you !